# Обновить корзину codeignither с другой ценой

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть Интернет магазин. Построен на codeignither. Ситуация такая, что есть товар с 4 разными ценами. Цена за одну штуку, цена за 2 штуки, цена за 3 штуки, цена за 4 штуки. Добавление товара сделал.

```
function add_cart(){
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $count = $this->input->post('count');
            $cart = array(
                'id'      => $id,
                'qty'     => $count,
                'price'   => $this->input->post('price'),
                'name'    => $this->input->post('title'),
                'images'    => $this->input->post('images')
             );
            $product = $this->pages_model->get_product_info($id);
            if ($cart['qty']==1){
                $cart['price'] = $product['price'];
            }
            if ($cart['qty']==2){
                $cart['price'] = $product['price2'];
            }
            if ($cart['qty']==3){
                $cart['price'] = $product['price3'];
            }
            if ($cart['qty']==4){
                $cart['price'] = $product['price4'];
            }

            $return['rowID'] = $this->cart->insert($cart);
    }
```

Некоторые куски кода опустил. Суть проста, я получаю id продукта и другие параметры. Потом проверяю, какое кол-во добавил, и соответсвенно присваиваю данную цену. Но как сделать так что бы работало при обновлении кол-ва? По Update Работая такая функция.

```
function update_cart(){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->cart->total_items(); $i++)
       {
            $item = $this->input->post($i);
            $data = array(
                    'rowid' => $item['rowid'], 
                    'qty' => $item['qty']
            );
            $this->cart->update($data);
       }
       redirect('pages/cart');
}
```

Обновляет только кол-во по заданном rowid. Цену нельзя обновить(((( Что сделать можно?

Comment: Как пробовали обновить цену? Почему решили, что нельзя обновить? Пробовали передавать `price` в переменную `$data` на основе сработавшего `if`, как в примере выше? До выполнения метода `update`, конечно же.

Comment: Да пробовал не работает.

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку

Comment: Укажите в вопросе о какой версии CodeIgniter идет речь. Согласно документации, обновлять можно любое свойство, которое было вставлено. http://codeigniter3.info/guide/libraries/cart#updating-the-cart

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос. Всего лишь нужно сделать так как тут.
http://blog.thecodingbox.me/codeigniter-cart-class-extended-to-update-price/

А потом обновлять уже и с ценой