# Обновление цены товара в codeignither часть 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

В продолжении вопроса об обновлении цены. Первая часть [тут.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526673/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-codeignither-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Цена обновляется все прекрасно. Но вот одно но, есть два товара, у них разные параметры, допустим цвет и другие. Они добавляются в корзину как отдельные товары. Но цена должна идти как за два экземпляра, потому что это по сути один и тот же товар, только с разными параметрами.
Ниже принстрик[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я при обновлении передаю id товара, он одинаковый а значит по нему можно узнавать тот же товар или нет. Только вот как логически понять что в корзине два товара не могу(((( Подскажите алгоритм?

Ниже обновление товара.

```
function update_cart(){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->cart->total_items(); $i++)
       {
            $item = $this->input->post($i);
            $id_product = $item['id'];
            $data = array(
                    'rowid' => $item['rowid'], 
                    'qty' => $item['qty']   
            );
            $product = $this->pages_model->get_product_info($item['id']);
            if ($item['qty']==1){
                $data['price'] = $product['price'];
            }
            if ($item['qty']==2){
                if ($product['price2']!=0){
                    $data['price'] = $product['price2'];
                } else {
                    $data['price'] = $product['price'];
                }
            }
            if ($item['qty']==3){
                if ($product['price3']!=0){
                    $data['price'] = $product['price3'];
                } else {
                    $data['price'] = $product['price'];
                }
            }
            if ($item['qty']>=4){
                if ($product['price4']!=0){
                    $data['price'] = $product['price4'];
                } else {
                    $data['price'] = $product['price'];
                }
            }
             $this->cart->update($data);
       }
       redirect('pages/cart');
}
```